# How to force Lightroom to use a specific lens profile?

Tags: lightroom, lens-correction, samyang

I use a Canon 6D and a Rokinon (Samyang/Bower) 14mm f/2.8 for some fun UWA shots. I had already downloaded a lens profile using Adobe Lens Profile Downloader to correct for the mustache distortion. Even though it was for a 5D2, it showed up and automatically applied when I selected "Canon" from the "Make" drop down list in Lightroom's Lens Correction panel. It wasn't perfect, but generally did the job.

This was all working fine until today, when it will no longer select that lens profile. It defaults to the Canon 15mm f/2.8 when I select "Canon" in the "Make" drop down, and if I select the "Profile" drop down, it doesn't even show up in the list available for selection.

Can I force LR to use a specific profile? How does it decide what to populate in that "Profile" drop down list?

Edit to clarify LR version 4 on Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: Could you please add your version of Lightroom and the OS you're using? This makes it easier for people to answer your question specifically. I don't use any correction profiles, but shouldn't the `Make` say Samyang/Bower and not Canon?

Comment: Yes, from the start, I thought that strange as well. If I had to guess, it is probably because of whoever created the Custom Lens Profile, might not have done it properly. Until it stopped working entirely, I never cared. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you have checked already, but could you look in `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CameraRaw/LensProfiles/` and `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CameraRaw/LensProfiles/` if the downloaded profile (a `.lcp` file) is present?

Comment: Not seeing them there. Would those be the default included profiles that come with RAW? Would the Profile Downloader store its downloaded profiles somewhere separately? Also, it's still showing the profiles as downloaded.

Comment: From what I read from the [Adobe help site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/3.0/Using/WS43660fa5a9ec95a81172e081210db09b94-7feb.html#WS67a9e0c3a11b14967d12e1d61285f7b6de9-8000) the profiles should be in one of the folders mentioned earlier. The default included profiles are found in the `/Library/...` folder, the manually downloaded ones are in `~/Library/...`.

Comment: I've only done some basic `ls`ing. I'll do some more invasive greping through the lcp's to see if I can find anything that would indicate a samyang downloaded profile.

Comment: This might be a stretch, but is there any chance you changed the type of file you're shooting (e.g., from raw to jpeg or jpeg to raw)? There are different profiles based on file type.

Comment: Oh, also, some tips for managing profiles here: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support-lightroom-4.html

Comment: Did you change/define user preset directory after you have installed lens profile?

Comment: @Novaktually, I think that actually might have been the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightroom uses the make and the model of the lens to filter the list of displayed profiles, as determined from the EXIF data or selectable from the drop-down lists, *as well as the file type (RAW or JPEG)*. you can see (and edit, if you are adventurous) these parameters n the .lcp files, i've successfully used a profile created for JPEG for my RAW's. (this, of course, is only advisable if your camera does not perform any in-camera lens corrections to the JPEG's).

Those .lcp profiles are just XML files, so you can edit them with any text editor. There's a line `<stCamera:CameraRawProfile>False</stCamera:CameraRawProfile>` where `False`means a JPEG profile, and `True` raw.

Comment: Can you share a bit more detail about _how_ you can edit the `.lcp`'s? I think with that data, we might have a good enough answer to check.

Comment: added some info.

Comment: I went ahead and checked this, but it would be nice to know where these files are stored, too. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: well, on my windows machine, they are in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\LensProfiles\1.0\Downloaded, but i don't know about mac.

Answer (score 0):

Kenny, my LR 5 is either suffering from the same amnesia or "something" in a Mac update (10.8.5 here as well) "somehow" messed up with LR. Yes, it's not probably. No, I don't have a better explanation.  :o(
I'm loosing profile info for my NEX lenses combos. I haven't had the time to check if it's consistent or not. It doesn't happen with the Nikon D7000.

As a possibility for you to explore, if a particular make / lens combination is important for you and LR is not doing a good job, download the demo of DxO Optics 9 and/or DxO Point of View. Both are *way* better at correcting lens distortion because DxO has the best and biggest lenses / camera database in the planet - Adobe hasn't. Their NR and algorithms are more precise but I won't get into that. See for yourself, and rest assured you can have a hybrid workflow, as I do, for when it matters.

Comment: Agree with the idea of the hybrid workflow. When lens correction matters this much, it's worth using the best. I use DxO Optics for optical correction and Lightroom for final adjustments and file management, and invariably prefer the results for the DxO+LR images over those processed in LR alone.